# How can I remove "you've been logged out" when user tries to enter username again

Tags: php, html, forms, authentication

When a user logs out, they are redirected back to the login form. The login form looks at the login.php?logout=true url and if logout=true, then it displays "You've been successfully logged out." Not exactly sure how to do so otherwise as anyone can type logout=true and see that message.

How can I remove that text once the user tries to enter their username/password again?

login.php looks something like this:

```
<form method="post" action="login.php">

  <fieldset>

  <?php if ($disp_msg) { ?>
  <p><?php print($disp_msg); ?></p>
  <?php } ?>

  <p><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username"></p>
  <p><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password"></p>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Login"></p>

  </fieldset>

</form>
```

I'd assume I'd have to use JavaScript, although unfamiliar with it. Most likely would use onFocus or onClick in each input type field that somehow clears the output of $disp_msg

Comment: Use javasript `onkeypress` event.

Comment: Ok. And how do I clear the $disp_msg once printed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added two IDs. One is for your display message and other one is for your input box.

```
<?php if ($disp_msg) { ?>
<p id="msg"><?php print($disp_msg); ?></p>
<?php } ?>

<p><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" id="username"></p>
<!-- other input fields -->
</fieldset>
</form>

<!-- jQuery Code -->
<script>
$('#username').keypress(function(e) {
   $('#msg').empty();
});
</script>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HP9s5/)**

`##################################################################`

```
<!-- without jquery -->
<!-- Add attribute onKeyPress in username input field. -->
<input type="text" id="username" onKeyPress="fun()"/>
<!-- and add this just before you </head>. Remove previous jquery code-->
<script>
    function fun()
        {
            document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML="";
        }
</script>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zMbH8/)**

Comment: Does not work for me. Does the jquery code need to go below the form or can it be in the <head> section?

Comment: You'll need to add jquery library. add this just before `</head>` 

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`
then
enclose that jquery code into script tag just after above code and before `</head>`

Comment: demo works. Copied everything over like you said and its not doing anything for me.

Comment: remove jquery library and jquery code and see the edit and 2nd demo. That's all i can do

Comment: Ok, so the <script> has to go below the </form> for it to work.

Comment: Using jquery, how can I use this to work with 'username' and 'password'?

Comment: HTML comments are like this: `<!-- comment -->`